# Using AWS Instance to run games off Steam

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have been learning about AWS recently and I had an idea.  My personal laptop is small, I use it for coding and keep all my files on the cloud.  My work laptop is huge, but I can't game on my work laptop.
I have a few games Im looking at on Steam that just wouldn't fit on my personal laptop.  Do you think it would be cost effective to download them onto a server through AWS and play them like that?

Comment: how do you want to play games on a server? Does the server have a GPU to render the frames? How do you want to stream the video content from the cloud to your machine without lag? Look at e.g. google stadia and how much (wo)manpower they spent on it, if they cannot do it properly you certainly won't be able to achieve it...

Comment: In addition to what is already mentioned in the comments, this is not a programming question, so it is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue my comment. Cost-effectiveness is not really the issue but rendering and lag is the issue.

On your PC / Laptop you want to go for 60 frames per second (fps), meaning at max ~13ms of rendering per frame. Depending on the type of game you can get by with 30fps, but e.g. for first person shooters you might even try to go for 144+ fps.

The key thing to understand is that your action, e.g. moving around or clicking something has to be rendered as soon as possible, e.g. at most 13ms after you do it. You will immediately notice a high input lag meaning a "long" time between an input being issued and the input taking effect. If you now move the rendering to the server the frame does not only need to be rendered but it needs to also be transferred onto your machine. Depending on your bandwidth and the image size this can naively easily take a second. This is extremely far beyond anything that is actually playable. And that does not yet account for you sending your interaction to the server to make the server render it.

Long story short: it is not feasible for *you* to implement. As already mentioned Google Stadia tries to achieve that but you can be sure there are A LOT of optimizations in place to make it work.